# Inserir novas colunas com decrição de ID´s em tabela já existente

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela denominada produtos, está tabela já possui os campos necessários para a sua utilização, mas agora tenho a necessidade de incluir mais 4 (quatro) colunas na mesma, colunas essa que serão a descrição de alguns ID´s que tenho, a estrutura da tabela atualmente está assim:

```
IdProduto | IdDepto | IdSubDepto | Idmarca | IdModelo | Codigo | DescProd | Tamanho | largura
```

Agora preciso inserir a descrição de cada ID´s nessa tabela mantendo os campos já existentes, a mesma deverá ficar assim:

```
IdProduto | IdDepto | DescDepto | IdSubDepto | DescSubDepto | Idmarca | Descmarca | IdModelo | DescModelo | Codigo | DescProd | Tamanho | largura
```

As colunas a serem inseridas são: DescDepto, DescSubDepto, Descmarca e DescModelo

Não consegui visualizar uma possibilidade que pudesse me ajudar a resolver esse problema.

Comment: Essas colunas novas são para manter um historico da ultima descrição? fazer um view com uns join pegando a descrição não resolveria?

Comment: Olá @rray, as novas colunas deverão manter a descrição do ID, nunca fiz uma view, mas vou dar uma pesquisa, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um `alter table`, como comando do mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE nomedatabela ADD nomedacoluna VARCHAR(255);
```

E caso você queira inserir ela depois de determinada coluna, pode usar como exemplo esse outro comando:

```
ALTER TABLE nomedatabela ADD nomedacoluna VARCHAR(255) AFTER colunaanterior;
```

Comment: Olá @Striter Alfa, obrigado pela dica, mas como fica se as tabelas a serem inseridas possuírem valores esses comandos resolvem?

Comment: Caso as colunas sejam nullables, a tabela ganhará as novas colunas e os novos valores serão null em cadas um dos resultados. Caso não deseje que as colunas sejam null, você precisa colocar um valor default quando criar as colunas, e depois, alterar com os corretos. Como já foi mencionado, é mais fácil trazer a descrição usando inner join com outras tabelas ao invés de duplicar valor, caso ele for o mesmo de outra tabela.